# Finding $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\cos x-1}{x^3}$

Tags: limits

I understand that in order for the limit to exist, the limit as $x$ approaches from the left of 0 has to be equal to the limit as $x$ approaches from the right of 0. In this case, I found that one leads to infinity and the other leads to negative infinity. However, the answer from the book claims that the limit is negative infinity.

Comment: As others have noted, the book is wrong. Unfortunately, confusing $\lim_{x\to0}$ with $\lim_{x\to0^+}$ is an all to easy mistake - apparently, even occasionally for book authors.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x -1}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\cos x+1}\right)\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2.$$

I think you are right.

Comment: $\frac{\cos x -1}{x^3}\ne \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so the book is wrong and you are right. Indeed first notice that

$$\left\lvert\frac{\cos x-1}{x^3}\right\rvert\geq\left\lvert\frac{x^2}{2x^3}\right\rvert=\frac{1}{2\lvert x\rvert}\to\infty.$$

Furthermore, notice that

$$\cos x-1\leq 0,$$

so the sign of $\frac{\cos x-1}{x^3}$ is the opposite of the sign of $x^3$, and so in particular,

$$\frac{\cos x-1}{x^3}\geq 0,\quad x\in(-\infty,0),$$
$$\frac{\cos x-1}{x^3}\leq 0,\quad x\in(0,\infty).$$

Combining these facts we get that

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^3}=-\infty$$

while

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^3}=\infty,$$

and so as the one-sided limits do not coincidence, the limit is **not** equal to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) twice to settle the question.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(x) - 1}{x^3} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\sin(x)}{3x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\cos(x)}{6x}. \tag1 $$

As $x$ goes to $(0^-)$ (i.e. approaches $(0)$ from below), the *far right* fraction in (1) above indicates that the (left side) limit is $$\frac{-1}{- ~(0)} = +\infty.$$

As $x$ goes to $(0^+)$ (i.e. approaches $(0)$ from above), the *far right* fraction in (1) above indicates that the (right side) limit is $$\frac{-1}{+ ~(0)} = -\infty.$$